# If drag the polygon get the LatLng in AGM angular4

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am using [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/) to get the LatLng of the selected area in the form of a polygon. Now I draw the polygon I successfully get the LatLng points according to the polygon. But when I drag the pointer to polygon from any point of polygon its LatLng points do not change. I want to change them on drag.

**Component.html:-**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="options.lat" [longitude]="options.lng" (mapClick)="onMapClick($event)">
   <agm-polygon [paths]="paths" [editable]=options.editable  [visible]="options.visible" [draggable]=options.draggable [fillColor]=options.fillColor>
   </agm-polygon>
</agm-map>
```

**Component.ts:-**

```
paths : Array<LatLngLiteral> = [];

options : any = {
  lat          : 33.5362475,
  lng          : -111.9267386,
  zoom         : 10,
  fillColor    : '#DC143C',
  draggable    : true,
  editable     : true,
  visible      : true
};

public onMapClick(evt) {
   let clickCrd = { lat: evt.coords.lat, lng: evt.coords.lng };
   this.paths.push(clickCrd);
   let newArray = Array<LatLngLiteral>();
   this.paths.forEach((item) => {
     newArray.push(item);
  });
  this.paths = newArray;
}
```

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xua16q)

Please tell me how it is possible?

Comment: you can use `blur` event to change the lat long..

Comment: I have already used but it does not work.

Comment: can you create a `stackblitz` with the issue??

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xua16q